# Slick slider not working height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I just discover the [slick "the last carousel you will ever need"](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

and i try to make some test with it bit nothing is working :/

i make a little code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.6/slick.css"/
<div class="sliderlastvideos">
   {% for video in lastvideos %}
       <div class="videocontainer">
           <div class="video">
               <img src="" alt="">
               <div class="video-titre">Tritre video</div>
           </div>
        </div>
   {% endfor %}
</div>
{% block javascript %}
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.6/slick.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.sliderlastvideos').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3
});
```

CSS

```
.videocontainer{
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
.video{
  margin: 10px
}
img{
  width: 100%
}
```

that's suppose to give me simple slider but give me a huge one on 2 line of videos.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/maxenceboucas/4Dn3b/)

plz help me :p

thanks

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle? I Tried to make one, but there must be some code missing.

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxenceboucas/4Dn3b/) :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed your jsfiddle, I've made some changes to the html structure too.

The main problem seems that the slick plugin doesn't like that margin and width in the .videocontainer css class.

Don't know if there is any bug in slick or we are initializing it incorrectly:

```
.videocontainer {
 background-color: white;
 margin: 5px;
 text-align: center;
}
.sliderlastvid{
 width: 300px;
 margin: 0px auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Dn3b/2/

Update: When I go backwards in the slider, some videocontainers do show up below, only to be fixed right after. Check slick homepage for any issues you might have: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: An other problem just pop [http://jsfiddle.net/maxenceboucas/4Dn3b/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/maxenceboucas/4Dn3b/3/).

Comment: @user3800515 Post another question in stackoverflow with that issue

Comment: can't ask an other question :/

Answer (score 0):

You have typos so the library isn't being added added

```
<scripttype="text/javascript"src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.6/slick.min.js</script>
------^here                                   and missing quotes-------------------^
```

Should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.6/slick.min.js"</script>
```

You're also not closing the `$(document).ready`

Fixing the errors in your browsers console should fix the issues. Afterwards check whether the libraries are added in resources.

*BTW i'm wondering why you've a `<br>` inside the css?*

Comment: tx Tilwin :p

But all this tipos are not in my code but just from a wrong paste.